# Exclude files while packaging an extension

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am trying to create an Azure DevOps extension. As part of this, when I tried to use a npm package **azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2**,  it is failing when package extension is done using `tfx create extension` command showing the following error:

[image]

It is because of a license file included in the module in node_modules. When I deleted that file, it created the `.vsix` file successfully. Is there any alternative for this module? Or Is there a way to exclude a file while using the tfx create extension command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, this seems to be happening because of the whitespace in the name of the file **OpenSSL License.txt**. The easiest way to work around this could be to rename the file before running `tfx extension create` command.

If that doesn't help, please open an issue with the [azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks) repo. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13608) is a similar issue opened in the past.